# I'm trying to use this css style to styling my react app. But the css didn't work in my element, how to solve it ? I also using webpack and css-loader

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to use this css style to styling my react app. But the css didn't work in my element, how to solve it ?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import style from './styles/css/bootstrap.css';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button className={style['btn', 'btn-primary']}>test button</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import style from './styles/css/bootstrap.css';
```

What are you expecting the import to do? If it is to just include the css, then you don't need to give it a name.

```
import './styles/css/bootstrap.css';
```

Should be enough.

> style['btn', 'btn-primary']

Styling in react comes in various flavours. I would recommend reading the [official documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-styling.html) for it. Assuming you just want to use the classes: `btn` and `btn-primary`, you can just pass them to react as:

```
<button className="btn btn-primary">test button</button>
```